# Can anything 'beta' be permanent or for longer period?

Tags: word-usage

The adjective beta (in technology) means something which is still not finalized.

> [Beta (adj)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/BETA) - Preliminary or testing stage of a software/hardware product.

Now, I have observed many websites/software products **remain beta** forever! For instance, take this site only. I searched it on [WayBackMachine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130410131905/http://ell.stackexchange.com) and found that it has been *beta* since April 10, 2013 and may even **remain** for coming months/years!

[image]

**Now, the question -**

Nothing is permanent. Even if you add a new page or category or anything, it's update. This means what you have is **never finalized** and **bug** may come anytime, even to a foolproof and finalized product.

> Is there any specific period/milestone for what we can keep the word *beta* for our website/product?

If I go by books, preliminary or testing stage is called 'beta version' but then such **so called** beta websites are running full-fledged for months and years! Is that that the webmasters want to play safe and thus use the word *beta* forever?

Comment: Ah, I remember the word 'practice' for medical practitioners. It's practice forever! Is 'beta' considered the same way?

Comment: I don't know if you have read this page already: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle. According to my experience, most companies have their own definition of Beta, especially back in one or two decades ago. So, it can be somewhat arbitrary. By the way, I'd say that, given a complex enough system, we have no way to guarantee that a software system will have absolutely no bugs. And the reason for this non-guarantee-able is not just because of the constant updates, but mostly from the inherent nature of software.

Comment: Stack Exchange's definition of *beta* is rivaled only by Google's.

Comment: It's *beta* until it's met the criteria to move on to a different designation- so things stay *beta* until that time- however long that takes.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, though I suspect it might be better asked on one of the programming sites. Does *beta* have any *legal* meaning? -that is, does keeping something "in beta" limit implicit warranties and provide the creator protection against some legal actions? I would expect that to be a critical factor in use of the term.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it pertains to software development, but not to the English language in any. "beta" is an international term.

Comment: @laugh: That doesn't make sense. Languages can and do share words, but there are no words that are by definition shared by *all* languages, and it's topical to ask about cognates like "no" on both English and Spanish sites. If the term "beta" was too specialized for native speakers or English teachers to be able to answer reasonably, it might be off-topic, but it isn't; ELL can and does handle jargon specific to various fields as long as it's reasonably accessible to those who don't specialize in those fields.

Comment: @NathanTuggy However, as a language question, the given definition does not define a time frame. So why expect one? The application of a time frame or stage-frame will vary from situation to situation, and could depend on business, legal or other factors. Such SE sites would be a better venue for this question.

Comment: @user3169: Does "preliminary" carry any connotations of permanence or the reverse? Surely it is possible for an English teacher to give a solid answer on this word, used in the quoted definition!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name for products released by large corporations (including their release numbers and maturity "beta" label) is an executive decision based on a combination of marketing, legal, regulatory, and other business considerations (e.g. partnerships, contractual agreements).

---

The older, brick-and-mortar software-in-a-box sales and distribution model would never have been able to sell anything labeled "beta".  When software was first released on the Internet, businesses initially continued to "play fair" using Business 1.0 paradigms along with traditional release numbers and "properly" differentiated alpha/beta/production release designations.  This was simply because "that's the way it was always done".

But with Business 2.0 paradigm shifts, including the instantaneous distribution of software over the Internet, coupled with speed-to-market issues, businesses were pressured to release software and web services to the public at earlier points in the development cycle.

Another reason for maintaining beta could be due to the fierce competition on the Internet and possible disruptive innovations.  For example, Google's search engine strategy killed Yahoo's hierarchical catalog system, and Craigslist disrupted the entire newspaper industry.  With the ease of creating entirely new paradigms of user interaction, it's difficult to know if a particular strategy can maintain a competitive advantage for a long time.  Google may have been hesitant to pull the beta designation from it's Gmail interface as it watched for a possible "email-killer" paradigm/application.  As they continued to make partnerships and cement their Gmail application into the fabric of other Internet systems, Gmail became more and more likely to retain a long-term competitive advantage.  But if some other paradigm threatened Gmail, they would have needed to respond quickly with changes that could have been disruptive.

Google is widely known for releasing products as "beta" and maintaining that designation for many years as the products matured well beyond what would traditionally be considered a "production" release.  Other companies are likely following Google's lead for similar reasons.

---

Note that open-source systems tend to follow a more traditional model:

- Release = Well tested and considered stable.
- Beta = Next release version, fairly stable, but still contains bugs which will be worked out while people test it.
- Latest = Daily build of fixes to Beta or new functionality.  Very likely to have bugs in the new functionality or in the bug fixes (bug fixes need to be tested to insure they do in fact fix the bugs and don't introduce some other adverse side effect).

---

From the perspective of a more traditional for-profit company that is releasing a corporate website, you would need to determine (or ask) how you will track your Software Configuration Management (SCM) as well as your Software Release Cycle.  For a larger company, beta (if there is such a thing) could be in-house testing only or may have some limited testing with a few clients.  A smaller company might consider beta closer to production.  From lower levels, code moves to higher levels with more integration to other systems and databases.  Once made "live" it would be considered a "production version" since the pages and code would be moved to production servers which would have corporate policies specific to production code such as 24/7 on call support, policies on who can make changes, when changes can be made, etc.